# questions about unordered_multiset_of in boost bimap

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-set, bimap, boost-unordered

I am implementing a `boost::bimap` and I am considering using `unordered_multiset_of`
but `unordered_multiset_of` need to pass a hash function and equal operator to it. And I cant get it right.

```
class MyClass
{
  std::string s1;
  std::string s2;
  bool operator == (MyClass const& myClass)
  {
    return (s1 == myClass.s1 && s2 == myClass.s2);
  }
};

namespace std
{
  template<>
  struct hash<MyClass>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& myClass) const
    {
      std::size_t Seed = 0;
      boost::hash_combine(Seed, myClass.s1);
      boost::hash_combine(Seed, myClass.s2);
      return Seed;
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  typedef boost::bimaps::bimap<boost::bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<client,std::hash<MyClass>, std::equal_to>, .......................................> MyBiMap;

  MyBiMap MAP;
}
```

it seems that my hash function and equal_to function gives error.
how do I fix it?
I believe `std::equal_to()` will automatically call my == operator defined in `MyClass`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool operator == (MyClass const& myClass)`

Must be `const` `bool operator == (MyClass const& myClass)const`
Othervise `std::equal_to` will not be able to use it, since it accept const references

```
template <class T> struct equal_to : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x==y;}
};
```

Comment: Hi Alexrider, One more question. I now have a bimap with unordered_multiset at both side. I want to check whether there is a relation between two objects. I can find syntex for find key but it seems there is no function provided for find relation, right?